# Where can I migrate my parse application?

Tags: android, parse-platform, migration

Since Parse.com was closing, I need a Backend as a service (BaaS) where i can migrate my parse app. And I want know if i need change something in my application. And if anyone can put a tutorial please paste it. Thanks for everybody!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you migrate to any other BaaS, you are going to have to re-code your app to support the new backend. The only exception is if you setup a [Parse Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) where you would only have to make minor changes to your client code.

If you choose to move away from Parse, and the Parse Server, there is a convenient [GitHub](https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives) that has a lot of alternative BaaS providers. Most BaaS providers have tutorials to make the integration of their service as easy for the developer as possible.